# Smooth scroll gives no functionality with React.JS (tried multiple packages)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction in relation to enabling smooth scrolling features whilst using React & Webpack.

To be specific my app foundation is using: https://github.com/truffle-box/react-box

Packages attempted:

https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll

https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll

https://github.com/ganderzz/react-scroll-to

https://github.com/flyingant/react-scroll-to-component

The only functioning scrolling feature I found that I discovered is:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0];

element.scrollIntoView();
```

Which works but is not a smooth scrolling function there is parameters to add that do make this a smooth operation but are not supported on chrome.

```
element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
```

I get ZERO response or console outputs when I implement this variation. If someone could help me I'd highly appreciate it.

Regards.

Comment: attempting with react-motion now and still nothing.

Comment: possible that webpack could be excluding a core library needed for scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Seem's that chrome has updated the method and it now works.

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0];
element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
```